# Run class in different Thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to show the status on a Raspberry PI using a LED. To do this I have a program in Python that will run class methods in background using threads.

This is the code I have written:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import os
import threading

status = 0

class LEDStatus(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global status
        self.current_value = None
        self.running = True 
    def run(self):
        global status

        os.system("echo gpio | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger")

        while True:

            for i in xrange(0, status):
                os.system("echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness")

                time.sleep(0.25)

                os.system("echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness")

                time.sleep(0.25)

            time.sleep(2)

        os.system("echo mmc0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    leds = LEDStatus()
    try:
        leds.status = 3
        leds.start()

        while True:
            print "X"
            time.sleep(2)

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): #Al pulsar ctrl+c
        print "\nFinish"
        leds.running = False
        leds.join()
```

After the program comes to this line `os.system("echo gpio | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger")`, it doesn't execute anything in the `run` method.

What am I doing wrong? How can I change the value of the status variable from the main method?

Comment: You are trying to use sudo in a `os.system` call, sudo waits for the admin password to be entered, but it can't since it has no pipe to receive it from.

Comment: Depends on sudo configuration, NOPASSWD might be at play. Or not. It does sound like it is the sudo though.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I've tested those lines in a main Thread and it works fine

Comment: @Ilja had the answer but deleted it. You set `led.status = 3` but that's not the global `status` being checked by the class instance.

Comment: Undeleted too, with a few words about sudo added.

Comment: If all the stuff behind the first call requiring sudo is not necessary, it's not a minimal example. Reduce your code to one before posting. Now, two more things: Firstly, you could call your program with `sudo` instead of trying to elevate privileges in the middle. Secondly, you should be able to configure access to the GPIOs so that you don't need root privileges. Also, upgrade to Python 3, it's stable and well-supported.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt excellent points, esp. on upgrading to Python 3, but actually the stuff behind the 1. call requiring sudo were the problem.

Comment: Should I update my question and put the code that works well now?

Comment: I'm halfway sure it doesn't require all iteration of an infinite loop to demonstrate the issue, @Ilja. ;) But still, it looks like the first sudo call is the only problem. No threading required. No further variables required. No class required even. No dead code after the infinite loop required.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What if I want to call this code from another class?

Comment: @ozat "Should I update my question and put the code that works well now?" - no, you shouldn't. There is already an accepted answer that highlights what needs to be done.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt OP did mention that the sudo actually worked fine. The problem turned out to be the mixture of global variables and instance variables. That mix was visible *outside* of the "infinite loop", since said variable was set in the `if` block way down and the global var declared in the beginning...

Comment: @ozat **especially do not remove the code that demonstrates the problem**. I've rollbacked your edit that removed `sudo` from those commands.

Comment: @ozat pretty sure you've meant to write `while self.running:` btw.

Comment: @Ilja Yes, you are right, when I was searching for the things that could be wrong I changed it to `True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `sudo` in `os.system()` call may block. It will sit there waiting for user input (the password). This depends on how `sudoers` file has been set up.

Your code also mixes global variables and class attributes. The `status` global variable is never updated, since you assign `self.status = 3` instead of `status = 3`.

Using global variables like this is a bit frowned upon, since you might as well really use a class attribute here. Change your `__init__` to take initial status as an argument.

```
def __init__(self, status):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.status = status
    self.current_value = None
    self.running = True
```

and in your `run` method use `self.status`:

```
for i in xrange(0, self.status):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Ilja , I was a little confused , it works fine now

Comment: The problem was caused by the global variable `status`